# Javascript error: this.form is undefined, I can't get an object variable in a member method

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I am using the following code:

```
 var frontPic = e.target.files[0]
 var frontPicName = frontPic.name
 var salonId=$("#salonId").val()
 upload = new Upload(frontPicName, salonId)
 upload.resize(frontPic)
```

To call the following code

```
function Upload(filename, salonId){

    var form = new FormData()
        form.append("filename", filename)
        form.append("salonId", salonId)
};

Upload.prototype.resize = function(file){
    $.canvasResize(file,
    {
        width: 400,
        height: 0,
        crop: false,
        quality: 100,
        callback: function (data)
        {
            alert(data)
            // Add file data
            this.form.append("file", $.canvasResize('dataURLtoBlob', data));
            $('body').css("background", "url("+data+")")
        }
    });
}
```

My alert(data) seems to work fine, so the actual resizing action looks fine.

However I am getting the error `this.form is undefined` for the line `this.form.append("file", $.canvasResize('dataURLtoBlob', data));`

What would be the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2):

You've got two problems in your code:

1. The `form` is declared as a local variable in the constructor, not as a property on the object.
2. `this` within your callback function is not referring to the `upload` object. You'll have to store it in a local variable.

```js
function Upload(filename, salonId){

    this.form = new FormData()
    this.form.append("filename", filename)
    this.form.append("salonId", salonId)
};

Upload.prototype.resize = function(file){

    var self = this;

    $.canvasResize(file,
    {
        width: 400,
        height: 0,
        crop: false,
        quality: 100,
        callback: function (data)
        {
            self.form.append("file", $.canvasResize('dataURLtoBlob', data));
            $('body').css("background", "url("+data+")")
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` probably is scoped to something else. You should create a reference before calling `$.canvasResize`.

```
Upload.prototype.resize = function(file){
    var self = this;
    $.canvasResize(file,
```

then replace `this` with `self`.

Comment: Thanks but I get the same error, except it says self.form is undefined etc. Could the issue be with how I am declaring the variables i.e. is var form = new FormData() incorrect for being able to access the form variable in the protoype method?